# How to add all images from a folder using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an empty div on my site where I want all images from a folder to be shown.

Haven't been able to understand how to get JS to do this, doing it manually would be extremely tiring since there's a lot of images. Sorry for the vagueness in the question but I really don't know how else to describe nor could I find anything online...

All I need is for it to fetch the image names in an array then it's just making a function that goes through the array and adds image elements, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some vanilla JS to get you started.

```js
fetch('/path/to/image/folder')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(fileName => {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = '/path/to/image/folder/' + fileName;
      document.getElementById('image-container').appendChild(img);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```